# $\{\gamma'(0)\,\vert\, \gamma \in C^\infty(\Bbb R,G), \gamma(0) = I_n\}$ is a $\Bbb R$-vector space where $G$ is a closed subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

> **Problem.** Let $G$ be a closed* subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$. Define $$V:= \{\gamma'(0)\,\vert\, \gamma \in C^\infty(\Bbb R,G), \gamma(0) = I_n\}$$
> Show that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$. Furthermore, determine $V$ explicitly when $G = GL_n(\Bbb C)$ and $SL_n(\Bbb C)$.
>
> *The topology on $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is due to the identification $M_n(\mathbb C) \cong \mathbb C^{n^2}$.

The first task is to show that $V$ is a real vector space.

1. Consider the constant map $\gamma:\Bbb R\to G$, $t\mapsto I_n$. Then, $\gamma(0) = I_n$ and $\gamma'(0) = \mathbf{0}_n \in V$. Note that $I_n \in G$ since subgroups preserve identities. So, $\mathbf{0} := \mathbf{0}_n \in M_n(\Bbb C)$ is the zero element of the vector space.
2. In addition, we must check the *[vector space axioms](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/resource/general/121.1.00s/vector_axioms.html)*. After @KReiser's hint, I have shown that $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication. Suppose $\gamma'(0) \in V$ for some $\gamma \in C^\infty(\Bbb R,G)$ with $\gamma(0) = I_n$. Define $\gamma_a \in C^\infty(\Bbb R,G)$ for $a\in R$, by $\gamma_a(t):= \gamma(at)$. $\gamma_a$ satisfies $\gamma_a(0) = \gamma(0) = I_n$. Then, $\gamma_a'(t) = a\gamma'(at)$ implying $\gamma_a'(0) = a\gamma'(0) \in V$ for every $a\in \Bbb R$. For $\gamma_1'(0),\gamma_2'(0) \in V$, consider $\gamma := \gamma_1\gamma_2 \in C^\infty(\Bbb R,G)$ to conclude $\gamma_1'(0) + \gamma_2'(0) \in V$, i.e. $V$ is closed under addition. This was suggested by @José Carlos Santos.
3. For $G = GL_n(\Bbb C)$, I can show that $V = M_n(\Bbb C)$. $V\subset M_n(\Bbb C)$ is obvious. Take $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$, and $\gamma(t):= e^{tA}$. Then, $\gamma(0) = I_n$ and $\gamma'(0) = A \in V$. So, $V = M_n(\Bbb C)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Would would the range of $t\gamma_1+(1-t)\gamma_2$ be a subset of $G$?

Comment: Right, not necessarily - so maybe that was a bad idea. I've edited.

Comment: The vector space axioms you need to check are additivity and multiplication by scalars, and you're working with a derivative. Can you think of what you have to put in to a derivative to get a sum or a scalar multiple out?

Comment: @KReiser I'm not sure I understand your hint, but in general, we do know that $\frac{d}{dt} f(ct) = c f'(ct)$ and $\frac{d}{dt} (f(t) + g(t)) = f'(t) + g'(t)$. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Could you elaborate? For the $\mathbf 0$ element of $V$, consider the constant map $\gamma:\Bbb R\to G$, $\gamma(t) = I_n$. Then, $\gamma(0) = I_n$ and $\gamma'(0) = \mathbf{0}_n \in V$.

Comment: Can you show that $V = M_n(\mathbb C)$ for $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ ?

Comment: For $SL_n(\mathbb C)$ you dont have the whole matrix space. See what the condition on the matrix path to lie in $SL_n(\mathbb C)$ gives as condition for the derivative.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper For $G= GL_n(\Bbb C)$, I have added a proof in the post.

Comment: You know this website well enough, don't edit your question making it completely different once you have many comments and answers. For a linear algebraic group in characteristic $0$ there is a purely algebraic way to find the Lie algebra: if $\mathfrak{g}\in M_n(K)$ then $\exp(t \mathfrak{g})$ is a formal series $\in G(K[[t]])$ iff $\mathfrak{g}\in Lie(G)$.  This leads to $Lie(G)=\ker(G(K[t]/(t^2)\to G(K))$.

Comment: @reuns I *just edited the title*, the problem is *still the same* as in the first post. As the first part was resolved, I wanted to draw attention to the second part. I hope that is okay? If not, kindly let me know. By the way, I have not yet studied Lie algebras, so I believe the question wants to use simpler machinery.

Comment: It is not ok neither to edit the title nor to ask the Lie algebra of many linear groups. In analysis you just check what conditions on the matrix $\mathfrak{g}\in M_n(K)$ (with $K=\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$) ensure that for all $t$ real, $\exp(t \mathfrak{g})\in O_n,SO_n,U_n,GL_n,SL_n$ and so on. The Jorden normal form of $\mathfrak{g}$ often helps.

Comment: @reuns Alright - I have rolled back to the original title, and excluded the other groups from the problem statement. I will try to figure those out on my own. If I need help, I will make a separate post; so that this post doesn't lose focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I briefly said in my comment, you have to find a condition on $\gamma'(0)$

For example let $G = SL_n(\mathbb C)$ and $\gamma : \mathbb R \to G$ that is smooth.

What you have is $t \mapsto \det(\gamma(t))$ that is a constant function over $\mathbb R$. Its derivative is given by
$$t \mapsto tr\left(\gamma'(t)\cdot  {}^t Co(\gamma(t))\right)=tr\left(\gamma'(t)\cdot  \gamma^{-1}(t)\right) $$
This function as the derivative of a constant function vanishes. In particular you have : $$tr \left( \gamma'(0) \right) = 0$$

Conversely for $A$ in $M_n(\mathbb C)$ and for $t $ in $\mathbb R$ : if $tr(A) = 0$  you have $\det\left(e^{tA} \right) = e^{t \cdot tr(A)} = 1$

In the end you have $V = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb C), \quad tr (A) =0 \}$

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted your answer; and edited the question statement to exclude the other groups. I will try to figure those out on my own (and I will make a separate post if I need help)!

Answer (score 1):

If $v_1=\gamma_1'(0)$ and $v_2=\gamma_2'(0)$, then\begin{align}(\gamma_1\gamma_2)'(0)&=\gamma_1(0)\gamma_2'(0)+\gamma_1'(0)\gamma_2(0)\\&=\gamma'_1(0)+\gamma'_2(0)\\&=v_1+v_2.\end{align}And, if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $\eta(t)=\gamma_1(\lambda t)$, then$$\eta'(0)=\lambda\gamma_1'(0)=\lambda v_1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 1 is superfluous if $V \neq \emptyset$, as it follows from 2. 1 can basically be seen as the proof of non-emptyness.

And for sum check explicitly by computing $$(\gamma_1\gamma_2)'(0)= \gamma_1'(0)\gamma_2(0) + \gamma_1(0)\gamma'_2(0) = \gamma_1'(0)I_n+ I_n\gamma_2'(0) = \gamma_1'(0)+\gamma_2'(0)$$ to be really complete.

Comment: Yes, I already did this (also suggested by José Carlos Santos). I believe that completes the proof that $V$ is a vector space. Do you have any ideas for the explicit computation aspect of the problem?

Comment: @delta-divine No, I haven't thought about that part. Try $n=2$ first, as $n=1$ is too trivial..(we just get $\Bbb R$)

Comment: Alright, I'll try that!